# Looping with a range of integers for 'numeric' inputs in QGIS Python Console

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, loop

I have been trying to run `r.sun.incidout` in a loop of integers (for the 'Day' option, type=integer) in QGIS Python Console. Since the `'day'` parameter takes an integer number for its value, I get the error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.10/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 106, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.10/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 137, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm
Incorrect parameter value for day
```

I am using the following code. I know the error lies in `dys` inside the paramms in my code. How can I parse the variable as a numeric in the loop?

```
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
    
Processing.initialize()
    
import os
import numpy as np
    
dayss = np.arange(1, 367, 1)
    
outdir = r'C:\***\swiss_rad_tiffs'

for dys in dayss:

    day_str = str(dys).zfill(3)

    print('Doing Day %s' %day_str)

    outfile = os.path.join(outdir, 'rad_%s.tif'%day_str)

    paramms = {'elevation': r'C:\***\dem_wg32_500m.tif', 'aspect':r'C:\***\asp_wg32_500m.tif', 'aspect_value': 270, 'slope': r'C:\***\slp_wg32_500m.tif', 'slope_value':0.0, 'linke': None, 'albedo': None, 'albedo_value': 0.2, 'lat': None, 'long': None, 'coeff_bh': None, 'coeff_dh': None, 'horizon_basemap': None, 'horizon_step': 1, 'day': dys, 'step': 1.0, 'declination': None, 'distance_step': 0.5, 'civil_time': None, 'time': 12.00, 'beam_rad': outfile, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER': r'C:\***\dem_wg32_500m.tif', 'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER': 0  }

processing.run('grass7:r.sun.incidout', paramms)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is `dys/dayss` is datatype `np.int64` when it should be `int`:

```
import numpy as np
dayss = np.arange(1, 367, 1)
print(type(dayss[0]))
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

Try `int(dys)` in your paramms dictionary:

```
paramms = {'elevation': r'C:\***\dem_wg32_500m.tif', 'aspect':r'C:\***\asp_wg32_500m.tif', 'aspect_value': 270, 'slope': r'C:\***\slp_wg32_500m.tif', 'slope_value':0.0, 'linke': None, 'albedo': None, 'albedo_value': 0.2, 'lat': None, 'long': None, 'coeff_bh': None, 'coeff_dh': None, 'horizon_basemap': None, 'horizon_step': 1, 'day': int(dys), 'step': 1.0, 'declination': None, 'distance_step': 0.5, 'civil_time': None, 'time': 12.00, 'beam_rad': outfile, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER': r'C:\***\dem_wg32_500m.tif', 'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER': 0  }
```

Answer (score 8):

Since you populate `dayss` list using NumPy `arange` method, type of items in the list is not `int`, instead, it is `<class 'numpy.int32'>`.

Just add `dys = int(dys)` to `for` loop.

```
for dys in dayss:
    dys = int(dys)
```

Or generate the list using Python `range` method.

```
dayss = range(1, 367, 1)
```